# Implementing BPSK using MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write some **simple** MATLAB code for plotting a BPSK but the code is not working.  Here is the code:

```
t=0:(1/1000):3;
figure(1);

s0=sin( (2*pi)*t );
s1=sin( (2*pi)*t+(pi) );

sout=[s0 s1];

plot(t,sout);
grid on;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot this code vectorized without having the need to use `hold on` as what Nematollah suggested.  Simply place each data trace in a **separate** column.  The `t` vector can be left alone.  The reason why your code isn't working is because you placed `s0` and `s1` and concatenated them to be a single 1D array.  `t` has 3001 elements while `sout` would have `3001 * 2 = 6002` elements.  The dimensions are incompatible, which is why you're getting the error.

You can plot multiple signals using `plot` without a problem without the use of `hold on`.  Just make sure that each trace is in a separate column.  With your code setup, you just have to transpose `s0` and `s1` and this will work.  As such:

```
t=0:(1/1000):3;
figure(1);

s0=sin( (2*pi)*t );
s1=sin( (2*pi)*t+(pi) );

sout=[s0.' s1.']; %// Change - transpose s0 and s1
plot(t,sout);

grid on;
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Notice that MATLAB automatically colour codes the traces for you, seeing as how each data trace is in a separate column.

---

## Edit

You now want to concatenate these two signals together (which is actually what BPSK is supposed to do).  We can easily do this by extending the time vector that you have and then tacking on the second signal when you're done like you did in your original post.  You can easily do this in the following way:

```
t=0:(1/1000):3;
figure(1);

s0=sin( (2*pi)*t );
s1=sin( (2*pi)*t+(pi) );

sout = [s0 s1]; %// Note we are concatenating now
tvec = [t t(end) + t]; %// NEW

plot(tvec, sout); %// Plot 2 signals together as 1
```

Take a look at this statement:

```
tvec = [t t(end) + t];
```

I create a new vector which had the original time vector that goes between `[0,3]`.  I then extend this vector so that we take the time vector from `[0,3]` and offset it by the **last** time value of the original signal, which is 3.  As such, we would then add a vector of `[3,6]` at the end, as we will have two signals that are 3 seconds each - thus 6 seconds.  This is what I get:

[image]

Looks like BPSK to me! :)

Comment: is it possible to plot s1 exactly after s0 finishes ?!

Comment: @eyadkht yes. I'll write an answer soon

Comment: @eyadkht - Done.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot one symbol time, you should plot both signals on the same plot like this.

```
t = 0 : (1/1000) : 3;
s0 = sin((2*pi)*t);
s1=sin((2*pi)*t+pi);
plot(t, s0);
hold on
plot(t, s1, 'r');
grid
```